# Using a text file to loop through PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I have a text file `test.txt` which contains a list of OUs where I need to count the number of users found within each OU.

`test.txt`:

```
"ou=MyOU1,dc=Mydomain,dc=net"
"ou=MyOU2,dc=Mydomain,dc=net"
"ou=MyOU3,dc=Mydomain,dc=net"
```

I am passing this to command in PowerShell:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Out-String | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "$_").Count
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the
following partition(s): 'DC=Mydomain,DC=net ,
CN=Configuration,DC=Mydomain,DC=net ,
CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Mydomain,DC=net ,
DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=Mydomain,DC=net ,
DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=Mydomain,DC=net'.
At line:1 char:62
+ ... ing) | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "$_").Count}
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

However, when I run the OU individually, it works.

```
PS> (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=MyOU1,dc=Mydomain,dc=net").Count
10782
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: **Use of `Out-String` is not only unnecessary in your code, but actually creates a *single* output string, which causes your command to malfunction**, because `ForEach-Object` is then only called *once*, with a *multi-line* string.

`Get-Content` by itself sends the lines of a text file individually through the pipeline, which is what you want:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | foreach-object {
  (get-aduser -filter * -searchbase $_).count
}
```

Note that `$_` already is a string, so you needn't enclose it in `"..."`.

Aside from that, *if* the lines in your file really contain `"..."`-enclosed strings, as your sample input suggests (probably not, because the error message does not reflect them), and you cannot fix the file itself, you'd have to *remove* these double quotes, as they otherwise become *part of the string* that is passed to `-SearchBase`:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | foreach-object {
  (get-aduser -filter * -searchbase ($_ -replace '"')).count
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NHunter. Please don't forget to accept the answer, if it solves your problem.